# Почему данный код не верен?

Tags: php

Никак не могу разобраться с isset.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <table border="1" align="center">
        <tbody>
            <form name='action' action='admin.php' method='POST'>
                <tr><td>Имя :</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' name='author'><br/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Заголовок :</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' name='title'><br/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Текст<br/>
                        новости :</td>
                    <td><textarea cols="30" name='news'>Введите текст</textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input name="submit" type='submit' value='Отправить'></td></tr>
            </form>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php
    require_once 'config.php';

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $name  = $_POST['author'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $news  = $_POST['news'];

        if (!isset($name)) {
            echo "Вы не ввели имя";
        }
        if (!isset($title)) {
            echo "Вы не ввели заголовок";
        }
        if (isset($news)) {
            echo "Вы не ввели текст новости";
        }

        else {
            echo "$name $title $news";

        }
    }

    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `isset` тут ни к месту, если вы объявили переменную - то она уже точно есть!
2) `else` непонятно ( вам ) к чему относится

Как вариант можно так:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $name  = $_POST['author'];
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $news  = $_POST['news'];
  $ok = true;

  if ( empty($name) ){
    $ok = false;
    echo "Вы не ввели имя<br>";
  }
  if ( empty($title) ){
    $ok = false;
    echo "Вы не ввели заголовок<br>";
  }
  if ( empty($news) ){
    $ok = false;
    echo "Вы не ввели текст новости<br>";
  }

  if ( $ok ){
    echo $name.' '.$title.' '.$news;
  }
}
```

Comment: А если не объевлять переменную , как можно сделать по грамотному ?

Comment: Объясните что вы хотите получить -  и тогда можно будет что-то подсказать.<br>
P.S. чем не устраивает код в ответе?

Comment: Ну организовать проверку на пустые поля по средством isset или empty

Comment: Будте добры подскажите

Comment: Подскажите а для чего создана переменная $ok ?

Comment: у неё название - говорящее) Просто таких параметров ( $_POST['author'] ) обычно очень много, и создавать огромное условие в конце - накладно, поэтому вот так....

Comment: если ответ вам помог лучше остальных - то проголосуйте за него ( слева от ответа - галочка )

Comment: @timka_s поправочка, `1) isset тут ни к месту, если вы объявили переменную - то она уже точно есть!` нет, isset так же проверяет, что значение переменной отлично от null.

Answer (score 0):

Будет выполнятся условие только тогда, когда isset($news) введена новость (не понятно почему все проверяется на отсутствие, а $news на наличие в $_POST)

Я думаю как-то так

```
if(!isset($_POST[name]))           
        {
            echo "Вы не ввели имя";
        }
        elseif(!isset($_POST[title]))
        {
            echo "Вы не ввели заголовок";
        }
        elseif(!isset($_POST[news]))
        {
            echo "Вы не ввели текст новости";
        }

        else

        {

            echo "$name $title $news";

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
  $err= array();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name  = $_POST['author'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $news  = $_POST['news'];
    if (strlen($name)<4 && strlen($name)>32) {
        $err[]="Вы не ввели имя";
    }
    if (strlen($title)<10 && strlen($title)>64) {
        $err[]= "Вы не ввели заголовок";
    }
    if (strlen($news)<3 && strlen($news)>1024) {
        $err[]= "Вы не ввели текст новости";
    }

    if(!isset($err))
        {
          echo $name."-".$title."-".$news;
        }
if (is_array($err))
     {
        foreach ($err as $key=>$value) 
       {
          echo "$value\n";
       }

     }

  }

?>
```